# Function that accepts both expanded arguments and tuple

Tags: python

Is there a *Pythonic* way to create a function that accepts both separate arguments and a tuple? i.e to achieve something like this:

```
def f(*args):
    """prints 2 values 
            f(1,2)
                1 2
            f( (1,2) )
                1 2"""
    if len(args) == 1:
        if len(args[0]) != 2:
            raise Exception("wrong number of arguments")
        else:
            print args[0][0],args[0][1]
    elif len(args) == 2:
        print args[0],args[1]
    else:
            raise Exception("wrong number of arguments")
```

Comment: What (other than indentation) is wrong with what you wrote?

Comment: I would argue that it's probably not wise to make your function polymorphic in this way ... But others might disagree.

Comment: To echo @mgilson, if your function expects two values, declare it to take two values. If a caller has a 2-tuple, they can always use `f(*(1,2))`. Don't bend over backwards to accommodate anticipated usage if it obscures the expected usage.

Comment: @chepner: althoug I agree some basic pythonic functions do this like `max` which can be used as `max(1,4,2,5)` but also as `max([1,4,2,5])`.

Comment: And min and max are implemented in C, so the stdlib is silent on the Pythonic way to do it

Comment: `max` is not imposing a limit on the number of arguments, though; it takes either *one* iterable or an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: @chepner: yeah but that is simply because here `f` is supposed to take two arguments. The general case is of course: either pass multiple arguments, or one iterable that is then "unpacked".

Comment: That is exactly my point: `f` *has* an expected, desired number of arguments, so don't hide that fact by claiming to take an arbitrary number of arguments via `*args`.

Comment: The reason of why i made the question now is mainly to learn more about python. The use case might be update the function conforming to 2 differnt standards

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Good point about `max()`; in fact `return max(args),min(args)` could be a valid solution, just for this specific case (if the order doesn't matter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I don't know if it is very wise to do so. Say a person calls a function like:

```
f(*((1,4),(2,5)))
```

As you can see the tuple contains two elements. But now for some reason, the person calls it with only one element (because for instance the generator did not generated two elements):

```
f(*((1,4),))
```

Then the user would likely want your function to report this, but now it will simply accept it (which can lead to complicated and unexpected behavior). Okay printing the elements of course will not do much harm. But in a general case the consequences might be more severe.

Nevertheless an elegant way to do this is making a simple **decorator** that first checks if one element is fed it checks if one tuple element is feeded and if so expands it:

```
def one_tuple(f):
    def g(*args):
        if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0],tuple):
            return f(*args[0])
        else:
            return f(*args)
    return g
```

And apply it to your `f`:

```
@one_tuple
def f(*args):
    if len(args) == 2:
        print args[0],args[1]
    else:
        raise Exception("wrong number of arguments")
```

The decorator `one_tuple` thus checks if one tuple is fed, and if so *unpacks* it for you before passing it to your `f` function.

As a result **`f` does not have to take the tuple case into account**: it will always be fed expanded arguments and handle these (of course the opposite could be done as well).

The advantage of defining a decorator is its **reuse**: you can apply this decorator to all kinds of functions (and thus make it easier to implement these).

Comment: Nice on the reuse. While the whole idea is probably deficient to begin with, OP will probably need to do this again once they start on this slippery slope.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I don't get why he needs to do this again: this is a simple decorator, if he defines a function `f_alternative`, he can attach the same decorator and thus work for instanced with tuples of length three (or arbitrary length) without having to worry about the one-tuple case.

Comment: I was saying that the idea of the expansion is questionable at best, but OP will probably start applying it to multiple functions. This makes your answer an efficient way to solve a bad problem, hence the +1. "Do this" was referring to the argument expansion, not to writing a separate decorator for each function.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: ah I get it. Well I agree it is questionable to do so, because it could give unexpected behavior.

Comment: As I commented in the answer , in my application I don't really need it and due to points some of you did I realize it is not a good idea. Anyway I think i came across a couple of functions that actually did this so i was courious about how it could be done. I like the decorator for it's elegance

Comment: @B-K: you are right functions like `min`, etc. do this. However I think this can be a bit dangerous...

Answer (score 3):

I do not agree to the idea myself (even though I like the fact that python does not require the definition of variable types and thus allows such a thing) but there might be cases where such a thing is needed. So here you go:

```
def my_f(a, *b):

    def whatever(my_tuple):
        # check tuple for conformity
        # do stuff with the tuple
        print(my_tuple)
        return

    if hasattr(a, '__iter__'):
        whatever(a)
    elif b:
        whatever((a,) + b)
    else:
        raise TypeError('malformed input')
    return
```

Restructured it a bit but the logic stays the same. if "a" is an iterable consider it to be your tuple, if not take "b" into account as well. if "a" is not an iterable and "b" is not defined, raise `TypeError`

```
my_f((1, 2, 3)) # (1, 2, 3)
my_f(1, 2, 3)   # (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: You do not have to convert to `list(..)` first, simply appending with an iterable is enough.

Comment: Only possible problem here is that it won't work with a single non-iterable argument. +1 because there is a 90% chance that OP won't care about that use-case.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The `join` is just a dummy example.

Comment: And furthermore I do not see how this actually answers the question: this answer semantically changes the functions since now if the tuple contains more than two elements no exception is thrown. The OP asked for a more elegant way to *define* the *same* function.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis. Actually, it would throw off the `else` to your `if b` test. I did not even get as far as the `join`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Now it does.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis. The `else` should have something like `try: iter(a); except TypeError: c = (a,); else: c = a;`.

Answer (score 3):

The *Pythonic* way would be to use duck typing. This will only work if you are sure that none of the expanded arguments are going to be iterable.

```
def f(*args):
    def g(*args):
        # play with guaranteed expanded arguments

    if len(args) == 1:
        try:
            iter(args[0])
        except TypeError:
            pass
        else:
            return g(*args[0])
    return g(*args)
```

This implementation offers a slight improvement on @Ev.Kounis's answer for cases where a single non-tuple argument is passed in. It can also easily be turned into the equivalent decorator described by @WillemVanOnsem. Use the decorator version if you have more than one function like this.